# Loading Image to Filestream

Tags: c#, filestream, openfiledialog

I am loading an image using

```
OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
```

After I select the file, "open" is populated with several items, including the path.

Now I would like to load the file into a filestream (or something similar) to be sent via a webservice... is this possible?

thanks

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Any other questions?

Comment: At the risk of straining my psychic abilities, I suspect that mouthpiec might actually be looking for some hint as to how to load the file.  If that were the case, they might want to look here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/e2f183aa-307e-463d-b846-1ad6418848a3

Comment: :) steven, i managed to load the file, eg I managed to load an image into a picture box, but I would like some code of how to load it onto a filestream

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can open the file with [`FileStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47ek66wy.aspx):

```
FileStream file = new FileStream("path to file", FileMode.Open);
```

You can then pass this through to the web service http context [Response.OutputStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.outputstream.aspx) property. You will still need to set the correct mime type and various headers, but this works well:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream = file;
```

Having said that, the easiest way to send a file from a web service (or web app) is to use the [Response.WriteFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dyfzssz9.aspx) method:

```
Response.WriteFile("Path To File");
```

Comment: What should I do if that "path to file" is an embedded BMP?

Comment: @warmth - access the embedded file as a stream and pass that to the output stream.

Answer (score 7):

try this:

```
byte[] buff = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(open.FileName);
System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(buff);
```

Comment: is it possible to recreate the document from buff?

Comment: i managed to convert to bitmap by using the normal "new Bitmap()"
constructor

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible to create an image

```
var img = Image.FromFile(/*path*/);
```

or into a stream

```
var file = new FileStream("path to file", FileMode.Open);
```

But hot it should be send it is up to You to decide

sendToWs(img)

Comment: if the image will be a bitmap, will it be saved in a bitmap? or if it is a jpeg, fill it be saved in a jpeg, and so on?

Comment: Image is an abstract class that provides functionality for the Bitmap and Metafile. For saving image You use the satatic method save Image.Save(path,format) where format is form ImageFormat