# C# Convert Image To FileStream

Tags: c#

My application so far lets the user select an image via the file selector and upload it through a file stream via FTP:

```
        Stream ftpStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        FileStream file = File.OpenRead(fileToUpload);
        length = 1024;

        buffer = new byte[length];
           do
            {
                bytesRead = file.Read(buffer, 0, length);
                ftpStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                totalReadBytesCount += bytesRead;
                var progress = totalReadBytesCount * 100.0 / totalToUpload;
                backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress((int)progress);
            }
            while (bytesRead != 0);
```

This works fine. 
The selected image is saved as a file and then uploaded.

Now, however, I wish to save it as a 'Image' so I can resize it etc. So that the code would be:

```
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            image = Image.FromFile(openFileDialog1.FileName);
        }
```

As opposed to:

```
  if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        file = openFileDialog1.FileName;
    }
```

My question thus is:

Now my selected file is a Image file. How do I convert it into the filestream? If this can't be done easily then how would I upload the image via ftp?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: try this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325762/loading-image-to-filestream

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To write the image to the filestream, I would recommend using the Save function of the Image class. I.E

```
image = Image.FromFile(openFileDialog1.FileName);
image.Save(ftpStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

Obviously, you'll need to check for errors and possibly use a different image format.

Comment: Apologises if this is a stupid quesiton. When I execut the application I get the following error on the 'image.save' line: "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: stream"

Comment: @user1662290 All it says is that you've given the image.Save function a null value for the stream parameter. In other words, `ftpStream` is null! You'll need to make sure what you're doing before hand is not causing ftpStream to become null. Post more of youre code if you need more help.

Comment: Hi.
Thanks for your response. Worked better than what already had.
My mistake was I was writing to the FileStream instead of the FTPStream. :/ oops
Works beautifully now! :D

Answer (score 0):

You may use [Image.FromStream Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.fromstream.aspx).

Something like this:

```
image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(buffer));
```

To save to FileStream use something like this:

```
var stream = File.OpenWrite(openFileDialog1.FileName);
image.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```