# How to create image file from vfp filetostr() string in c#

Tags: visual-foxpro, foxpro

Use vfp's filetostr() function to store the string returned by the image file into the text type field of sql server

So how to create a picture file after reading a string from sql server with C#?

What encoding is the string returned by filetostr and what type is it in C#

Comment: Your question does not seem to be consistent. VFP's `FileToStr()` returns a so-called `binary string` i.e. `Type()` would return "C", the Vfp table data type would be Char(nn) `NoCpTran`, i.e a Char() string without Code-Page transformation. But then your next sentence is asking for the same in C#? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14979841/c-sharp-convert-image-to-filestream

Answer (score 1):

FileToStr() reads any file either binary or not. You never store a binary file to SQL server's text field. Text data type is depreceated anyway. You use Varbinary(MAX) instead.
There is no special encoding returned with FileToStr(), it simply reads any file as is with no character encoding conversion. IOW, you can think it as ASCIIEncoding. In C# it is byte[] (not a char[]) - same as doing a File.ReadAllBytes()-. If you look a file using a hex editor, you would see hex bytes, FileToStr() gets all those bytes as a single string (unlike C#, in VFP a string can contain any ASCII character including character 0x00).

You can simply get it as a byte[] and create Image using Image.FromStream(). ie:

```
void Main()
{
  byte[] mySavedPic; 
  using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"server=.\SQLExpress;Trusted_connection=yes;Database=ImageDb"))
  {
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Picture from  myPictures where pictureId = 1",connection);
    connection.Open();
    mySavedPic = (byte[])cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    connection.Close();
  }
  
  
  Form f = new Form();
  PictureBox p = new PictureBox();
  p.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
  p.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
  
  using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(mySavedPic)) 
  {
      p.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
  }

  f.Controls.Add( p );
  f.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: Just one remark: Binary isn't the same as ASCIIEncoding. In .NET we have Encoding.ASCII which is a 7-bit encoding and would not yield the same result as treating the file as a stream or array of bytes.

Comment: @ChristofWollenhaupt, very true. I didn't want to say it is ASCIIEncoding but like ASCIIEncoding. Sorry if I did.